# Calling javascript file from NPAPI plugin code

Tags: javascript, events, google-chrome-extension, npapi

i have created a chrome extension. now, i want to change it to a NPAPI plugin. i have used npsimple sample code(from chrome) to build plugin. now the issue is:

i have following java script chrome extension file 
code:

```
//test.js

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) 
{   
    //this file calls content script file  
});
```

this file is called when ever i click on extension icon. now we don't want to call this file by clicking on extension(want to call it when plugin is loaded). so we can have some other event also.
now  i have to call test.js file from NPAPI plugin.i have no idea how can i do that. can we fire some fake event from NPAPI plugin inside NPN_INVOKE and register a listener in js file and execute js file.
or 
is there any way to inject this file in NPAPI code.

is there any other better way..

please help..
thanks in advance...

Comment: I hope you are aware that chrome+chromium dropped NPAPI support: http://blog.chromium.org/2014/05/update-on-npapi-deprecation.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options.  You can use [NPN_Evaluate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/NPN_Evaluate) or you can get a reference to the `window` object with [NPN_GetValue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/NPN_GetValue):

```
NPObject* window;
NPError err = NPN_GetValue(pNPP, NPNVWindowNPObject, &window);
```

Once you have the window NPObject then you can invoke global javascript functions with [NPN_Invoke](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/NPN_Invoke) and get/set properties with [NPN_GetProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/NPN_GetProperty) and [NPN_SetProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/NPN_SetProperty).

You might consider using [FireBreath](http://firebreath.org), which hugely simplifies all of this.

Comment: i am able to call js file. now i have another issue. can you help me in injecting the plugin in content script. can you please check what is wrong with this code:                                                                function addIt(){
  myEmbed = document.createElement('embed');
  myEmbed.attributes(added attributes here);
  document.getElementByTagName('head')[0].append('myEmbed');
}

Comment: that should be a separate question, and this one needs to be marked as answered if this answer was sufficient.  Comments are fine for clarification, but not for entirely new unrelated questions.  I will say, however, that it is unlikely that adding an embed or object tag to the head of a document will be effective -- it needs to be in the body